# I want after googlemap initialize do some events, how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

My personal define layer loads slowly, I want to after the all Google map including my layer loading do some Javascript stuff; how to do it? How to find the initialize finished events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) - chances are you want to use the event `tilesloaded`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'tilesloaded',yourFunction)
```